# How can one resend a received email as totally NEW email? So no forwarding or re-directs

Tags: php, email, outlook, sendmail

This has been a massive headache. We use Ning as a our platform for an arts event project. We want to ask our audience to upload photos to our website via an email address. The only issue is that Ning only will give us ridiculous email addresses for this purpose... such as photos34628234896@ourwebsite.com That hardly sticks in the mind!

So I thought, lets just forward emails from an easy to remember email address to the Ning's crazy one... BUT Ning doesn't allow any emails to upload photos if they are detected as being forwarded or redirected. I guess that detection is done through the email header.

So that is why I need a way to redirect an email to another address without that being reflected in the header info in the email. I thought perhaps Outlook receiving the emails from the easy to remember email address, then somehow resending them with a fresh clean header may be the answer? I can code in PHP, and run a home headerless ubuntu server on a domestic internet connection too if that may provide a better answer?

Any thoughts how I could achieve this goal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can forward the email to your server you can have it piped to PHP which can then resend the email for you with whatever email address you wish to be displayed. Just make sure you have things like [DomainKeys](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DKIM) and [SPF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sender_Policy_Framework) records set up for that server or else your chances of the mail being seen as spam will increase.

Comment: Wow, that was a very quick answer. Thanks. Are there any places I could read online that may outline the technique to pipe received emails to PHP?

Comment: What control panel does your server use? If it is cPanel I *know* there are tutorials for this as I have used them personally.

Comment: I have a homegrown ubuntu server that is headerless. I also have shared server accounts online with 1&1 (currently not a fan), and also  tsohost. I'm guessing a shared server wouldn't let me add such scripts though?

Comment: This looked good as a way to pipe on a home linux server? http://www.damnsemicolon.com/php/parse-emails-in-php-with-email-piping-part-1

Answer (score 0):

If you are using an Exchange server, you can use Transport rules to redirect the message, which will pass most forwarding checks.  If it does indeed change the headers or something else, you can use the same ruleset to remove or modify them.  Most MTAs(Mail Transport) will allow the same sort of functions, but it really depends on which one you use.  Postfix is quite flexible.

The changes will be made in 
Exchange Management Console
Origanization Configuration
Hub Transport
Transport Rules

Also, and maybe easier, you could simply try to add a secondary delivery address, in the mail flow settings for the fictional user you assign to receive the emails.  This would be done in the user properties.  Server level forwarding amy not trigger the forwarding blocks that you are encountering, as client forwarding does not work the in entirely the same way.  Many clients send the email again, but the server redirects it.

Exchange Management Console
Recipient Configuration
Mailbox
Properties, Mail Flow Settings.

You would enable forwarding in Delivery Options.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, just noticed that you are using ubuntu, you can simply have postfix redirect the email for you, you will use Postfix Virtual Alias Maps...

Here is a link that describes it perfectly...

http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-bsd-postfix-forward-email-to-another-account/